# How do I create a centered div of uncertain width containing left-aligned elements?

Tags: html, css

I have several uniform blue elements (`<div style="display: inline-block;">`) inside a red div inside a purple div. [Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylTm9.png) (imgur).

I would like the blue elements to be left-aligned (as many in a row as will fit in the purple div width), with a red div shrink-wrapped around them. But then I would like the red div be horizontally centered inside the purple div.

I was hoping to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3wVTx/1/) (jsFiddle), but that only works if the red div has a specified width.

Comment: Have you tried setting a margin for the red div? So for #red, set a margin:20px. It would create a spacing effect between the purple border and the red border.

Comment: "But then I would like red div be horizontally centered inside the purple div" - For this to happen, you MUST specify the width of red div.

Comment: Do you actually need the red div, rather than just having the blue elements centred within the purple div?

Comment: Never mind, my idea doesn't work on the last line of blue elements anyway.

Comment: Sagar: I don't know the width of the purple div, so I don't know what margin would be needed to center the red div. And I can't use margin:auto, since I don't know the width of the red div either!

Comment: Srijan: In that case, what workaround can I use?

Comment: Neil: FWIW, I don't actually need the red div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning to this problem, I have found a solution with inline CSS and no javascript (which were additional constraints I didn't mention).

If it's stupid and it works, it's not stupid! At least that's what I'm telling myself.

My solution is padding the end of the list of child elements with several "invisible" equal-width 0-height inline-block elements. I ended up not needing the "red div" to accomplish this result.

Here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3wVTx/8/

Comment: This is a really creative solution. I like it.

Comment: The only problem is when there aren't enough elements to fill the first row. Then the appear left of center.

Comment: That is intended. I want the items to be left-aligned.

Comment: This is great! Like Mike said, really creative. I was researching my own problem and have a wrapper div with a max-width which works even better with this solution. With a max-width you can center the wrapper on the page while still left-justifying the content. Plus there is a maximum number of spacer div's needed because you will never have to fill up more than a maximum number spaces before the items clear another row. Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbhomxg2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Would putting a margin on #red not work? Granted this would depend on if anything else will be inside of #purple. Is this not what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/3wVTx/3/

Comment: I don't think so. I would like "as many [blue elements] in a row as will fit in the purple div width", so the margin I want might be anywhere between 0 and half the width of a blue element.

Comment: Hmm, so #red will vary in how far away from #purple it is? If you resize the area in that jsfiddle you will see the blue elements will move to fit inside #red depending on the width of the browser (should be able to resize your browser or drag the middle bar between javascript and result). The only thing I can think of is if you are wanting to have #red exactly the size of how many blue elements will fit (to avoid the white space if only half a blue would fit)?

Comment: In my jsFiddle, the blue elements reflow correctly based on the size of the purple div. The only problem is that the entire set of blue elements is itself not centered--it hugs the left edge of the purple div.